# UITableViewCell custom button image not updating in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I have three buttons link, share and favourites in my cell. I have manually set the images in my custom cell class. In the willDisplay method of tableview delegate I want favourites image to update after the user taps on it. The service is working fine on the backend and the object is being added/removed from the favourites but the image is not updating. I have tried setting up the background image instead of image and also deployed various techniques prescribed for Objective-C but nothing seems to workout in my case. Initially I was setting up the image as the same in the DealsFullTableViewCell

This is willdisplay code snippet I'm talking about

```
if (self.dealArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl.characters.count > 0){
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealsFullTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DealsFullTableViewCell

    if DataBaseReadServices().getFavourtiesforItemId(self.dealArray[indexPath.row].dealId) == nil {
        cell.favouritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Favourites Blue Outline 20x20"), for: .selected)

    } else {
        cell.favouritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Favourite Icon Blue 20x20"), for: .selected)
        print ("=============")
    }
}
```

I am initializing the image in the DealsFullTableViewCell as

```
let favouritesButtonImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .starEmpty, textColor: Constants.AppColours().primaryColour, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20), backgroundColor: UIColor.clear)

self.favouritesButton.setImage(favouritesButtonImage, for: .normal)
```

Comment: you should have some flag from backend for selected/not selected.
Then you can reload table after tapping on favbutton. (after backend change done)

Comment: Which method does this code belong to?

Comment: @DimpleShah the database service is already telling me which image to show but it is not updating it

Comment: @vadian this belongs to willdisplay method of uitableviewdelegate when the cell is already displayed in the class where i've made an outlet for the tableview and the image is initialized in the custom class for the cell DealsFullTableViewCell

Comment: **Never ever** call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The method `willDisplayCell` passes the affected cell in the `cell` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much @vadian, this was the issue. i have casted it as a different cell and it is working perfectly fine. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below answer, if it is not working please change the thread.

```
            if(DataBaseReadServices().getFavourtiesforItemId(self.dealArray[indexPath.row].dealId) == nil){

                cell.favouritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Favourites Blue Outline 20x20"), for: .selected)

            } else {

                 cell.favouritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Favourite Icon Blue 20x20"), for: .normal)
              print ("=============")
            }`
```

Change the thread if above code is not working.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
//your code
}
```

Thanks